# How to compile all resources into one executable file?

Tags: python, compiler-construction, pygtk, glade, pyinstaller

I've wrote GTK application with python.

All graphical user interface is in glade file, and there are some images used. I wish to compile my application into EXEcutable file. For that I'm using **[PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/)** compiler and **[UPX](http://upx.sourceforge.net/)** packer.

I've done as manual says:

```
python Configure.py
python Makespec.py --onefile --windowed --upx /path/to/yourscript.py
python Build.py /path/to/yourscript.spec
```

PyInstaller works perfectly and create one exe file. But to make my application work correctly i have to copy my *glade* and *image* files into exe's folder.

**Is there any way to compile those files into executable?**

I've edited my spec file in various ways but i can not achieve what i want. Spec file below only copies file to directory, but does not compile into executable file

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
a = Analysis([os.path.join(HOMEPATH,'support\\_mountzlib.py'), os.path.join(HOMEPATH,'support\\useUnicode.py'), 'r:\\connection\\main.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Documents and Settings\\Lixas\\Desktop\\pyinstaller-1.5-rc1'])

pyz = PYZ(a.pure)

exe = EXE( pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name=os.path.join('dist', 'NetworkChecker.exe'),
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=False,
          icon='r:\\connection\\ikona.ico'        )

coll = COLLECT(
    exe,
    [('gui.glade', 'r:\\connection\\gui.glade', 'DATA')],
    [('question16.png', 'r:\\connection\\question16.png', 'DATA')],
#   a.binaries,
#   strip=False,
    upx=True,
    name='distFinal')
```

I wish to have only one executable file with everything included into

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PyInstaller *does* allow you to bundle all your resources into the exe, without the trickyness of turning your data files into .py files -- your COLLECT object seems to be correct, the tricky step is accessing these files at runtime. PyInstaller will unpack them into a temporary directory and tell you where they are with the _MEIPASS2 variable. To get the file paths in both development and packed mode, I use this:

```
def resource_path(relative):
    return os.path.join(
        os.environ.get(
            "_MEIPASS2",
            os.path.abspath(".")
        ),
        relative
    )


# in development
>>> resource_path("gui.glade")
"/home/shish/src/my_app/gui.glade"

# in deployment
>>> resource_path("gui.glade")
"/tmp/_MEI34121/gui.glade"
```

Comment: This is no longer an environment variable, this is now stored in `sys._MEIPASS`

Comment: @favilo: Can you tell us how that will change this code to make it work?

Comment: You may be able to help solve my [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41073132/pyinstaller-app-is-accessing-txt-files-but-not-writing-to-them-works-before-ap).

Answer (score 6):

With a few changes, you can incorporate everything into your source code and thus into your executable file.

If you run [`gdk-pixbuf-csource`](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk-pixbuf/stable/gdk-pixbuf-csource.html) on your image files, you can convert them into strings, which you can then load using [`gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_inline()`](http://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gdkpixbuf.html#function-gdk--pixbuf-new-from-inline).

You can also include your Glade file as a string in the program and then load it using [`gtk.Builder.add_from_string()`](http://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtkbuilder.html#method-gtkbuilder--add-from-string).

Comment: That was idea that i thought of earlier- incorporate resources in script. Thank you for pointing me the way how to incorporate resources into app exe file.

Comment: +1 because in light of the comments of the OP this makes possible to obtain what he wanted to. I still miss to understand what the advantages of having everything in a single runtime file are, though... but this is not a problem of your answer, of course! :)

Comment: You may be able to help solve my [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41073132/pyinstaller-app-is-accessing-txt-files-but-not-writing-to-them-works-before-ap).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to compile those files into executable?

Strictly speaking: no, because [you compile source code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler), while the glade file is XML and the images are binary data. What you would normally do is to create an installer (i.e. a self-unpacking archive that will place different files in the correct directories when the installer is ran).

**EDIT:** If your concern is simply to have a one-file executable (so it's not about "compiling" but really about the number of files that are permanently written on the filesystem) you could try to use [this script](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/SingleFileExecutable) based on [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/). What it does, is to create temporary files each time the program is ran, removing them when execution is completed.

**EDIT2:** Apparently what you are asking for is also possible under [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/). From the [documentation](http://www.pyinstaller.org/export/latest/trunk/doc/Manual.html):

> By default, pyinstaller.py creates a distribution directory containing the main executable and the dynamic libraries. The option --onefile specifies that you want PyInstaller to build a single file with everything inside.

Comment: I wish to make ultra-portable application, where you need to worry just about one file. But if it is not possible this way- i will try to implement image and glade files into python script code. **Thank you very much** Maybe someone else has any other opinions about my problem

Comment: @Lixas - I don't really understand why you want to pursue this road (I'm not criticising: I'm asking for clarification, as I can't see its benefits to the user, while I can see its drawbacks). However if what you care is the **number** of files and not the fact that they are executable, see my edit, where I linked a script that does pretty much what you asked for, if I got the documentation right.

Comment: You may be able to help solve my [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41073132/pyinstaller-app-is-accessing-txt-files-but-not-writing-to-them-works-before-ap).