# Background tkinter on other computers

Tags: python-3.x

I im a beginner and have a question. I made an exe file of my code and everything when well. After i transported it to another computer i got a failed script error. Understandable cause i link a image on my local computer.

Do you know an easy way to link a image or import it that i can my programm with a background on other computers ?

Python 3.4

Thank u guys!

```
C = Canvas(frank, bg="blue", height=250, width=300)
filename = PhotoImage(file = "G:\\frankscripts\opdrachten\giphy.gif")
background_label = Label(frank, image=filename)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
C.pack()
```

Comment: Which tool did you use to convert your script to an executable file? [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689410/how-to-compile-all-resources-into-one-executable-file) somebody tries this using `PyInstaller`.

Comment: If the image is in the same folder as your script it is only necessary to pass a relative path: `filename = PhotoImage(file = "giphy.gif")
`, and in the end you only need to place the image on the side of your executable.

Comment: @ventiseis i also used pyinstaller. It seems it is indeed not possible to put it in one file. i will try your link.

Comment: @eyllanesc thanx but i know. The problem is i only i want 1 exe file and no other files