# Made a game with pygame but i have to send all the images to my friends with the exe

Tags: python, pygame

I made a game using pygame. Whenever I share it with my friends I also have to send them all the images, fonts, and audio files. Is there any way where I can only send the .exe file and not the media files?
(I made the exe using auto-py-to-exe)

Comment: You should put your images inside your executable like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689410/how-to-compile-all-resources-into-one-executable-file).

Comment: @NoeXWolf  I tried that out but when I click on the exe it opens and closes within a second. Also the cmd tells "ValueError : too many values to unpack (expected 3)". Pls help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you make it a .zip or .rar and make your friends extract it?
That is the best solution, because or else you wouldn't just need to give them the images but they'd also have to download all the libraries and if you already have a .zip file just add the images into it

I hope this helped you

Happy coding - BSK - SK Studio

Comment: Yes! Did the same thing! Thank you