# How can I load models and sounds into my distributable?

Tags: python, build, model, distribute, panda3d

I have been trying to learn Panda3D through making a game through this Tutorial: https://arsthaumaturgis.github.io/Panda3DTutorial.io/

I have managed to complete Lessons 1-15, and the game works fine through a command prompt; however, when I use bdist_apps to make it a distributable, the game crashes every time that I try to load it.  When I go to the log, it gives me this error message:

Known pipe types:
wglGraphicsPipe
(all display modules loaded.)

:loader(error): Couldn't load file PandaSampleModels-master/PandaSampleModels-
master/Environment/environment.egg: not found on model path (currently: "/c/Users/hihos/Documents/Toontown Modding Project/Panda3D-1.10.9-x64/Projects/build/win_amd64;/..;/../models")

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "**main**", line 415, in 
File "**main**", line 28, in **init**
File "direct.showbase.Loader", line 298, in loadModel
OSError: Could not load model file(s): ['PandaSampleModels-master/PandaSampleModels-master/Environment/environment']

I am not very experienced in coding period, so I am not exactly sure how to fix a problem like this.  I have tried to add the folder of the models and sounds to the requirements.txt file; however, it would not allow for me to build the product.  I don't know if the models, images, and sound files are already included in the .exe file of the game or if I need to add them through some other means.

Here is how my File Paths are like:

-Projects (Carries all of the main files for the game: Game.py, GameObject.py, requirements.txt, and setup.py)

-p3d_samples-master (Contains the character model used in the game.)

-PandaSampleModels-master (Contains the UI, environment, and enemies.)

-Sounds_&_Music (Contains the Sound Effects and Music.)

All of these are within my Panda3D-1.10.9-x64 folder.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The setuptools package, with the `bdist_apps` option will just create an `.exe` file for python executable sources. The rest of paths should be placed on relative paths to the executable file and should be also distributed within a package.

If you want to create just a single executable, you should try a different package creator, like [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/). But should be noted that you will need to modify some of your code. Check out another response [How to compile all resources into one executable file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689410/how-to-compile-all-resources-into-one-executable-file)

Comment: This helps me to narrow down my question a bit more.  I don't really need to put everything into one executable file; however, I do need to know how to put these paths onto their relative paths to the executable file and how to distribute them within a package.

Comment: Where is exactly placed the .exe in your path structure?

Comment: It is in Panda3D-1.10.9-x64\Projects\build\win_amd64.

Comment: I just got my problem solved on another forum.  Thanks for your help anyway!